# Why is LANG environment variable wrong in shell?

Tags: terminal, applications, bash, console, environment-variables

When I start a Terminal (in Monterey 12.2.1) my LANG is `sv_SE.UTF-8`, which is fine.

When I start a shell, or any other sub-process that reads environment, from GUI Emacs it is set to `LANG="en_SE.UTF-8"`, which obviously is incorrect.

As I understand it, Terminal, with "set enviroment variables on startup" activated in the preferences, will construct LANG from your "Language & Region" settings. There I have Swedish as the primary language, English as secondary and Sweden as the Region.

But obviously there is some similar mechanism when reading the environment from a GUI application, but for some reason it gets it wrong.

In a Terminal all other locale is also set to `sv_SE.UTF-8`. In the GUI shell they are set to `C`, indicating that they are unset, rather than inherited from LANG.

What's even more strange is that `defaults read -g AppleLocale` in a GUI shell gives `sv_SE`...

Why is this, is it a bug or can I fix so that LANG is set correctly also in GUI environment?